# Tkinter Text widget: Configure font

Tags: python, text, fonts, tkinter, configuration

I have `Text` widget that I can configure the font families by:

```
textwidget.config(font=(Consolas,13))
```

That would configure the whole `text` Widget. I only want to tell `Tkinter` I want to make every input after the `Text` widget has been configured to be like how I changed it.

How can I achieve this. Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `tag` commands. You can change the selected text using this code:

```
number=0
def fontchange():
    textwidget.tag_add(str(number), SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
    textwidget.tag_config(str(number), font=(Consolas,13))
    number += 1
```

Obviously this is a very basic changer but if you want to change it to the end you could change the SEL_LAST to END. Read this [site](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) for more info on tags.